# WebRTC on local network

Tags: webrtc

I'm new to WebRTC and I was wondering if it's possible to have webRTC application on a local network without need for signaling since we have the IP addresses of all members on the network and if so how should I use RTCPeerconnectio to create an offer?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible.

Signalling is for more than just exchanging IP addresses. The clients also exchange information about media types and codecs.

You could possibly do some of the exchange via hard coding. But you would basically need to go through the whole negotiation, logging out all the candidates, offer, and answer. Even then I don't know if it would work the second time (with everything hardcoded). It also wouldn't work if you ever wanted to change media. It would be an interesting experiment.. but probably a huge waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done! But kradical is right there will need to be some configuration ahead of time check out [pion/offline-browser-communication](https://github.com/pion/offline-browser-communication)

Here are the things you need to worry about

- You don't need to hardcoded IP addresses anymore thanks to [mDNS candidates](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mdns-ice-candidates-00). If you know the hostnames of the two computers they can both change IP addresses, and still be able to connect.
- You need to know the DTLS certificate and ICE credentials ahead of time. If you look at the repo I shared you can see how it is done there. I did `Go <-> Browser` because it is the Open Source project I work on, but can easily be `Browser <-> Browser` as well.
- I would connect with only a DataChannel at first, and then re-negotiate with all the details around media (tracks you wish to send and supported codecs)